# Exists a nice python wsgi to manage MYSQL database locally ? or must i code one myself?

Tags: php, python, mysql, python-2.7, mod-wsgi

PHPmyAdmin is a script that is extremely crowded and not logical.
Webmin is controlled by google inc and thus they can virus you.

i need to manage MYSQL database in a basic way.

i am thinking a nice PYTHON + MOD-WSGI script on the local
linux ( centos for example )

you click on it and it opens up in firefox using apache

and then you can control anything in your mysql database.

perhaps it is also modifiable so you can do cool things with it.

does there exist such script or should i code this myself for more flexibility ?

Comment: You could check out MySQL Workbench: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Comment: Sorry but for MySQL in my opinion is best approach is pure console client. Postgres has great gui client )

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) as it is quite feature loaded and heavy, you might be interested in [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), which is made to be more lightweight. Though this is still in PHP...